# How to create objects from reading in a txt file in c++?

Tags: c++, file-io, constructor

I'm trying to create objects from a text file. It works for the first object but then I get a segmentation fault. MasterStudent is a BST of the student object.

```
    void DataBase::studentFileRead(){
  ifstream theFile("masterStudent.txt");

  int studentID;
  string name;
  string level;
  string major;
  double GPA;
  int advisor;

  while(theFile >> studentID >> name >> level >> major >> GPA >> advisor){
    Student newStudent(studentID, name,level, major, GPA, advisor);
    masterStudent.insert(newStudent.studentID, newStudent);
  }
}
```

Here is the text file it is reading in.

```
    12345 connor sophmore compsci 3.5 123
    78965 steve senior business 3.85 567
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question

Comment: Nothing wrong with the posted code. The error is somewhere else in your program. (Almost certainly the BST code).

Comment: @john, he is a new contributor. "I'm not really sure why you posted it" .... maybe he is doing his best? This is why people are scared away from SO. You should consider rephrasing your comments in the future.

Comment: @David Let that be an early vaccine, I still collect downvotes and disagreements though I try my best. There's nothing "new" about it.

Comment: @David if new contributors don't take the tour and don't know that they should include a mcve in a question then they need to be told. Nothing scary about that, is it? Trying to explain why the question is not answerable is trying to help

Comment: Yea I made a dumb syntax error, thanks for the feedback! I'll make sure to use a minimal reproducible example next time! :)

Comment: @David Originally I thought that the `masterStudent` collection was something like `std::map` but then I read that it was the OP own BST class. The OP is no beginner, the posted code is of good quality. I'm sure the OP is smart enough to suspect that the problem is in the BST code. So I just wondered why this code was posted.